# Hide the next 3 columns iteratively if the previous 3 are hidden google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Starting from column 9 I would like to hide the next 3 columns which I have successfully done using the below script which will hide column 9,10 and 11 (I,J and K)

```
   function hideEvent() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    sheet.hideColumns(9, 3);
    }
```

But what I want to do is hide the next 3 columns after that if columns 9-11 are already hidden and if columns 12,13,14 are hidden then hide the next 3 and so on.

I found that you can grab the hidden status of a column using `isColumnHiddenByUser(columnPosition)` but I wasn't sure how to use that output to loop through and iterate.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

So this is where I have got to thanks to @Marios. One slight hiccup I can't seem to get my head around is how do I reassign `start` to be +3 each time, so that when this function meaning `start` will reference to column 15,18,21,24 and so on.

```
  function Event() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    const steps = 3;
    let check = true;
    let start = 12;
    let Ncols = start + 3 ;
  
    while (start<Ncols){
      for(let i=start - steps ; i<start ; i++){
        if (!sheet.isColumnHiddenByUser(i)){
          check = false;
        };
      };
      if(check){  
      sheet.hideColumns(start, steps);
      start = start + 3;
      };
      Logger.log(start); //Produces 15 
      return start;
    };
}
```

Another solution I had was to count the number of hidden columns which I think may be more robust. As hidden column + 8 would be the `start`

Comment: Actually I am not sure if your logic makes sense. If `9-11` are hidden, then the script will hide `12-14`. But since `12-14` is hidden now, the script will hide `15-17` etc.. and every other column will be hidden as domino.

Comment: @Marios I have a button that I want the user to click in order to hide the next 3 columns but only the next 3 if that makes sense. When the next user comes along they will hide the 3 of the previous user etc

Comment: @Marios I just updated the question to maybe suit a new logic

Answer (score 2):

## SOLUTION

- Counted the number of hidden columns `cnt` , this count would then be used as part of the variable `start`
- `Start` is the columnIndex
- `Steps` is numColumns
- I add 9 to cnt because that is my start index or the first column I want to hide

  ```
   function Extra() {
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
   const max = sheet.getMaxColumns();
   let cnt = 0;
   for (i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
           if (sheet.isColumnHiddenByUser(i)) {
                   cnt += 1;
           }
   }
   const steps = 3;
   let start = cnt + 9; {
           sheet.hideColumns(start, steps);
           return;
      }
   }
  ```

**Thank you to those on this thread for your help**

Comment: @Marios special thank you to you and your other Q&A threads on here, i see you are quite to contributor so big kudos .

Comment: glad I was able to help you :)

Comment: consider upvoting answers that helped you find the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
function hideEvent() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  
  for (var i = lastCol; i > 0;i--){
    if (sheet.isColumnHiddenByUser(i) == true){
      sheet.hideColumns(i+1, 3);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, that looks pretty much what I had in mind. But it doesn't seem to be working. The one thing you added that surprised me was the last column bearing in mind this sheet has columns down to QD @RemcoE33

Comment: how come you decided to use last column?

Comment: Well it looks for a true/false. If you hide 4-9 and on 4 this is true then hide the next 3 will do no good.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite follow, I have updated the question to show my progress

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

I am not sure if your logic makes sense. If `9-11` are hidden, then the script will hide `12-14`. But since `12-14` is hidden now, the script will hide `15-17` etc.. and every other column will be hidden as domino. What you can do is to simply check if columns `9-11` are hidden. If they are hidden, then hide the rest of the columns in your sheet:

```
 function hideEvent() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    const Ncols = sheet.getMaxColumns();
    let check = true;
    
   for (let i=9; i<12; i++){
   if (!sheet.isColumnHiddenByUser(i)){
          check = false;
      };
   if(check){
     sheet.hideColumns(12,Ncols-12)
     }    
   }
 }
```

Comment: woah, completely different to what I had in mind. But guess it work, the only issue is that it runs and runs recursively. I would like it to run once and hide the next 3 on each click of the button I made.

Comment: *CORRECTION* you edit/update does not seem to work at all

Comment: @unstacked55 when you say something does not work then explain what is not working. Do you see any error ? Also as I explained in my answer , the code will hide the rest of the columns **when** all three columns 9-11 are hidden. If you want to run it every time manually then you need to select the limits manually. Ignore `Ncols` and use a hardcopy number instead.

Comment: @unstacked55 like I said **multiple** times already. Make sure columns 9-11 are hidden.

Comment: Can confirm columns 9-11 are hidden, sorry I should have mentioned that

Comment: I feel like part of my solution is to count the number of hidden columns. Your current solution hides all the columns. The pre edited version was closer to what i intended